# How to extend Django Admin model readonly_fields without having to specify all model fields (but still see them)

Tags: django, django-admin

In a Django Admin model, if I don't provide a `fields` or `readonly_fields` tuple, it will display the model's default fields.

But if I want to add a calculated field, like:

```
class SomeModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('get_calculated_field',)
    fields = ('get_calculated_field',)
```

then it will override all its fields and just display this one.

Is there a way to extend the `SomeModel` fields and add the calculated field on top of that, so that all of the model's existing fields don't have to be added to the tuples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add only the `readonly_fields` setting (and **not** the `fields` setting). That will cause it to include all the default fields plus the calculated one:

```
class SomeModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('get_calculated_field',)
    # Note: no 'fields = ...' setting here
```